# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot a CCDF graph in **Python** by reading data from a text file "data.txt".
Anyway, I got an error "**ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence**".

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code in python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

read = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
with open('data.txt') as f:
    a = [map(float, line.split()) for line in f]

sorted=np.sort(a)

x2 = []
y2 = []
y = 0
for x in sorted: 
    x2.extend([x,x])
    print x2
    y2.append(y)
    y += 1.0 / len(a)
    y2.append(y)

plt.plot(x2,y2)
plt.show()
```

And here is my text file "data.txt":

```
9.500000000
2.500000000
3.500000000
4.500000000
6.500000000
1.500000000
```

Comment: Why do you create the `read` array and then completely ignore it?

Comment: This one is not the problem. I can also remove it. Is there a problem with this?

Comment: hi @user2357112. I had removed it, but the same error still occurs. What should i do? Any change in my code?

Comment: Can you show us the _full_ trace back?  What is the shape of `x2` and `y2`?

Comment: x2 stands for the sorted data in text file. And y2 stands for CDF which is ranged from 0 to 1.

Comment: I gathered that, but what shape do you expect them to be?

Comment: What do you mean by shape?

Comment: It runs fine (copy and paste into IPython).  It's not how I'd write the Python (and numpy), but I don't see anything that would produce that error.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj. If I run this, it will make a CDF Graph...But I want to make a CCDF graph. What should I change in my code? I just know that CCDF = 1-CDF.

Comment: You need to submit a new question for that.  That is no longer a programming error, but a mathematical one.  Does CDF = 'cumulative distribution function'?

Comment: Yes. CDF = 'cumulative distribution function'. And CCDF = Complementary Cumulative Distribution Function.

Comment: I am sure that CCDF = 1- CDF
But I just don't know how to apply this in my code. Any idea please...

Comment: @hana please don't remove your code from the question. People need to see the code to see what is going wrong.